# Запрос, который будет выводить полное имя сотрудника, год приема на работу, и количество коллег, которые устроились с ним на работу в один год

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle-study

Необходимо написать запрос, который будет выводить полное имя сотрудника, год приема на работу и количество коллег, которые устроились с ним на работу в один год.

Не могу вывести коллег которые устроились на работу в том же году что и сотрудник.

```
SELECT first_name ||' '|| last_name AS Full_Name , extract(year from hire_date) as Y_E_A_R, 
(select count(*) 
  from hr.employees ee
  where ee.department_id=e.department_id) as count
FROM hr.employees e
order by hire_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да хотя бы вот так:

```
SELECT e.first_name ||' '|| e.last_name AS Full_Name 
  , extract(year from e.hire_date) as Y_E_A_R
  , (select count(*) 
    from hr.employees ee
    where ee.department_id=e.department_id
    and extract(year from e.hire_date) = extract(year from ee.hire_date)) as count

FROM hr.employees e
order by e.hire_date
```